# NLTK Word Extraction

Tags: machine-learning

So I am trying to read a txt file, process it by taking out the stop words, and then output that result into a new file. However, I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object
```

This is my code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 

f=open('tess1.txt','rU')
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
raw=f.read()
word_tokens = word_tokenize(raw) 
text = nltk.Text(word_tokens)
filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words] 
if w not in stop_words: 
    filtered_sentence.append(w) 

K = open("tess12.txt", "w")
K.write(filtered_sentence)
K.close()

print(filtered_sentence)
```

Comment: try K.write(str(filtered_sentence))

Answer (score 0):

The solution's to write a string inside the buffer:

```
K.write(str(filtered_sentence))
```